# How to make AddLogger method more generic in ServiceCollectionExtensions - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a `ServiceCollectionExtensions` class which has an `AddLogger` method. It all works fine but I was wondering if there is a way to make it more generic.

For an example, I have class A which depends on class B and class B depends on `ILogger<B>`. Setting DI dependencies `InitServices` works but is brittle because if class A's implementation changes and starts using other dependencies, the `InitServices` will need to be updated as well.

`TestBase` class:

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase<TService, TImplementation>
where TService : class
where TImplementation : class, TService
{
    protected TService Sut(Action<IServiceCollection>? configureService = default)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogger<TImplementation>();
        services.AddSut<TService, TImplementation>();

        configureService?.Invoke(services);

        return services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<TService>();
    }
}
```

`ServiceCollectionExtensions` class:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddLogger<TCategoryName>(this IServiceCollection services) where TCategoryName : class
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<ILogger<TCategoryName>>());
        return services;
    } 
}
```

Test class:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SessionID()
{
    // Arrange
    var swa = Sut(services => InitServices(services));
}

private static void InitServices(IServiceCollection services, bool refreshTokenGrantEnabled = false, bool passwordGrantEnabled = false, bool stsEnabled = true)
{
     services
         .AddSingleton<B>()
         .AddLogger<B>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that using `Mock.Of<ILogger<...>>()` is not that meaningful. Personally I would just use `NullLogger` with open generic registration:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(NullLogger<>));
```

Or using the standard setup with `NullLoggerProvider`:

```cs
services.AddLogging(l => l.AddProvider(NullLoggerProvider.Instance));
```